# Excel 2007 Pivot Tables: Refreshing upsets my manual formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, formatting, pivot-table

How can I stop a refresh on Pivot Tables from ruining my manually configured columns widths? I'd like to be able to make the columns fixed. The columns will always be the same ones, but the data obviously changes and new data goes in to those columns.

Any pointers, guidance, or workarounds are much appreciated.

Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right mouse click in the pivot table and select PivotTable Options.  Then on the layout & Format tab, unclick "Autofit column widths on update".

Comment: Ironically I found this hidden gem this morning.

Comment: don't ask me why the default is to adjust them.  I'm always unclicking it.